# Spacetime Fabric Curvature

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, grids

I'm using Illustrator to create a 10x10 grid that I wish to manipulate so I can achieve this effect:

[image: Spacetime Curvature]

But I'm unsure how to do it. Using the various Warp filters does not achieve the result I need, and I am unaware if there is a freehand "grab" distorting tool somewhere.

Comment: there are several tools for manipulating shapes. But they all fail because your effect has so many overlapping layers. it takes 5  minutes to manually draw the shape though so i wouldnt spend much time searching for a magick tool. And yes there is a grab distorting tool in your toolbar it just wont work in this case.

Comment: Im thinking that perhaps I should create a 3D funnel shape, and then map the grid to the inside face.

Comment: Ill write a example with some strategies after i arrive home. But this is quite easy

Answer (score 4):

This is quite easy to achieve using a few simple lines connected by a blend. Just create one half of the grid, then copy, rotate and mirror the effect for the other "axis".  It would take about as much time as tracing the original, but would offer live editing abilities if you wanted to tweak the distortion.

The image below took about 5 minutes to make. 12 of the 20 lines are generated by the blend effect. Only two lines need to deform, and the rest automatically deform to those.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @13ruce Sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding your explanation.

Comment: That's understandable. I glossed over a lot of the setup, assuming that you would know how to build the basic grid and set up the blends. It's pretty straight forward. Set up four horizontal lines, evenly spaced. (important: Be sure that the hierarchy of the lines is consistent from top to bottom. Select line 4 and "send to back". Select lines 3 and 4 and "send to back'. Select lines 2, 3 and 4 and "send to back". Otherwise the blends may not connect contiguously.) Before creating the blend, go to Object>Blend>Blend Options and set the blend to "Specified Steps" with 2 steps.

Comment: Now select the four lines and select Object>Blend>Make. You should see two lines appear between each of the preexisting lines. I then added a point to each line about a quarter of the way across (this helps the blends transition smoothly), and on the third line, I moved the anchor and dragged the anchors how I wanted them. Then I duplicated the blend mesh, then mirrored and rotated it 90º. Then I selected all of it and rotated 45º. Then I reduced the height to make the grid look like an isometric perspective grid. Last, I tweaked the handles a bit to get the deform effect looking right.

Comment: Let me know if you hit a sticking point, and I'll try to clarify further.